# Optimize integer multiplication with +/-1

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to optimize multiplication of an integer with -1/1 without using any multiplication and conditionals/branches?

Can it be done only with bitwise operations and integer addition?

**Edit**: The final goal is to optimize a scalar product of two integer vectors, where one of the vectors has only -1/1 values.

Comment: Like this: `i = ~i + 1;`?

Comment: your suggestion negates the number with 2's completement but where is the condition (1, -1) ?

Comment: @alk that only multiplies with -1, I only know at runtime whether it's -1 or 1

Comment: Reading yours comments, I feel I somehow did not got the question.

Comment: give `-O3` to compiler, if it doesn't generate the best code then file a bug

Comment: Bench your code before trying to optimize. Compilers are probably much smarter than us when it comes to optimizing, and processors have come a long way since times where you needed such micro-optimization. Just check https://ideone.com/jTsYvL for instance.

Comment: For reference, on a modern CPU you can do one multiplication per cycle in scalar code - and you can also only store one result per cycle. So the multiplication is not even a bottleneck. With SIMD it's a different matter..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for instance, the following function returns `a*b`, where `b` is either `+1` or `-1`:

```
int mul(int a, int b)
{
    int c[3] = { -a, 0, +a };

    return c[1+b];
}
```

or if both `a` and `b` are restricted to `+-1`:

```
int mul(int a, int b)
{
    int c[5] = { +1, 0, -1, 0, +1 };

    return c[a+b+2];
}
```

Yet another variant without memory access (faster than the ones above):

```
int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return 1 - (signed)( (unsigned)(a+1) ^ (unsigned)(b+1) );
}
```

This answer works with any signed integer representation (sign-magnitude, ones' complement, two's complement) and does not cause any undefined behaviour.

However, I cannot guarantee that this will be faster than normal multiplication.

Comment: Clean and portable! But strictly speaking, `mul(INT_MIN, 1)` does have undefined behavior on a 2's complement architecture even though the result is perfectly defined.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, you are right. However, the second variant does not suffer from this.

Comment: Yes indeed, for obvious reasons :)

Comment: Cool, but it's much slower than multiplication :)

Comment: @DoeJensen: benchmarking these hacks is rather tricky: does the function get inlined in all versions you compare? What compiler and flags do you use?

Comment: @chqrlie I have not used function calls, just pasted the code into the inner loop. It's about 8-10x slower probably due to additional memory accesses.

Comment: @mrks: nice benchmarking framework, but the C++ idioms are obtuse and emetic IMHO.

Comment: Just for the record: On my side, the proposed multiplication is about 10 percent slower than the `*` operator. http://rextester.com/RXAJ86393

Comment: @DaBler: I wouldn't be surprised if most of the time is spent in `(a&1)?+1:-1` and `(b&1)?+1:-1` in your benchmark.

Comment: @DaBler: I modified the code with inlining and precomputation of the values: the straight multiplication is 4 to 10 times faster than the hacks: http://rextester.com/DZDGPN36301

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed. Better to completely get rid of indirect memory access. I have added another fast variant without UB: http://rextester.com/RWK76061

Comment: @DaBler: I added similar code for the other case where only `b` is +1/-1. The hack is only slightly slower than the direct multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Most modern processors have an ALU with a fast multiplier (meaning it takes about the same time to add two numbers as to multiply them, give or take one CPU clock), so doing anything but `for (i=0;i<VectorLength;++i) { p += (x[i] * y[i]) ; }` isn't likely to help. However, try a simple `if` and see if that gives any benefits gained from the CPU's branch prediction:

```
for (i=0;i<VectorLength;++i) { p += (y[i]<0) ? -x[i] : x[i] ; }
```

In any case, if the CPU has fast multiply, doing any trick that involves more than one ALU operation (e.g., negation followed by addition, as in some of the examples given here) will more likely cause loss of performance compared to just one multiplication.

Comment: I have checked all methods mentioned here (including branches) and none of them beat straight forward multiplication on my CPU.

Comment: This is in complete agreement with what I expected. What CPU are you running on? Anything other than **very** old Intel CPUs, a low-power micro controller or a low-end RISC CPU will have a fast multiplier, so it is best to stick with multiplication.

Comment: I'm running on Intel i5. Although I will need this specific optimization for a low-power GPU, so I will check in the next few days on that.

Comment: Then, as you have likely guessed already, you can only get a definitive answer once you test on the target processor.

Answer (score 1):

```
int Multiplication(int x, int PlusOrMinusOne)
{
    PlusOrMinusOne >>= 1; //becomes 0 or -1
    //optionally build 2's complement (invert all bits plus 1)
    return (x ^ PlusOrMinusOne) + (PlusOrMinusOne & 1);
}
```

Here a nice resource for such [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: works, but I'm concerned because bit shifting on signed integers is implementation defined or undefined behaviour.

Comment: Nice. I've benchmarked this and unfortunately it's still not faster than straight forward multiplication :(

Comment: You could subtract `PlusOrMinusOne`, subtracting -1 is of course the same as adding 1

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, no, because C allows for three different integer representations:

- Signed magnitude
- Ones' complement
- Two’s complement

There is a [proposal to strictly make it two's complement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html) but until that makes it into the standard, you don't know what your negative numbers look like, so you can't really do too many bit hacks with them.

Less strictly speaking, most implementations use two's complement, so it is reasonably safe to use the hacks shown in other answers.

Comment: Let's hope this proposal makes it to the C Standard too. Too bad it is submitted for C++ and not C, where it would make sense the same way, except maybe for allowing padding bits on crippled micro-controllers. The Knuth's reference is a gem: 1's complement shall be written *ones' complement*. The motto *Reducing the nerd-snipe potential inherent in C++ is a Good Thing* remains wishful thinking I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm afraid DaBler proved you wrong with a portable solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2's compliment for integers:

```
int i1 = ...; // +1 or -1
int i2 = ...; // +1 or -1
unsigned u1 = i1 + 1; // 0 or 2
unsigned u2 = i2 + 1; // 0 or 2
unsigned u = u1 + u2; // 0 or 2 or 4: 0 and 4 need to become 1, 2 needs to become -1
u = (u & ~4); // 0 is 1 and 2 is -1
int i = u - 1; // -1 is 1 and 1 is -1
i = ~i + 1; // -1 is -1 and 1 is 1 :-)
```

The same as one-liner:

```
int i = ~(((i1 + i2 + 2) & ~4) - 1) + 1;
```

The following is true for `i1` and `i2` being either `+1` or `-1`:

```
i == i1 * i2
```